# Change color theme DT table

Tags: shiny, dt

How can we change color theme of DT table in shiny app? By default, it uses dark and light-grey color for alternate rows. I am using `formatStyle(target = 'row', backgroundColor = c('yellow', 'red')`. But it does not work as it works on columns only

```
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = 'title')
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem('dashboard', tabName = 'dashboard', icon = icon('dashboard'))
  )
)
body <- dashboardBody(
           box(
             title = 'box', width = NULL, status = 'primary',
             DT::dataTableOutput('table2')  
  )
)

ui<-dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server = function(input, output) {
  output$table2 = DT::renderDataTable(
    iris, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do, note that i left the header color white:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(DT)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = 'title')
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem('dashboard', tabName = 'dashboard', icon = icon('dashboard'))
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tags$style(HTML('table.dataTable tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: pink !important;}')),
  tags$style(HTML('table.dataTable tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: yellow !important;}')),
  tags$style(HTML('table.dataTable th {background-color: white !important;}')),
  box(
    title = 'box', width = NULL, status = 'primary',
    DT::dataTableOutput('table2')  
  )
)

ui<-dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server = function(input, output) {
  output$table2 = DT::renderDataTable(
    iris, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]